# Restrict access of an uploaded file to only the original author in a web application

Tags: php, web

Ex: a user login to a website and uploads a profile pic. I want to restrict the access to only allow the user that uploads the pic gets to have access.

So, if a second person somehow gets the URL to the pic, he or she still can not access it because she or he doesn't have the right permission(https://example.com/profile_pic_mike_1). Right now i have it so that the user can upload a profile pic but then anyone that has the URL are able to type in the browser and see the pic. I dont want that.

This is a project for fun so all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How do your script know if users has permission to access the picture?

Answer (score 2):

Create a script that's only accessible to logged in users. Have that script fetch the image and display on screen.

Your users access the following url:

```
example.com/image.php?name=image
```

You then have **image.php** fetch the file from disk/database, and return it to the user. A quick example assuming you're working with jpeg images (excluding error checking):

```
<?php

    if(!logged_in())
        die('Unauthorized');

    $filename = '/path/to/images/' . $_GET['name'];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    header('content-type: ' . image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_JPEG));

    echo $contents;
```

Other image mime types can be found here: [image_type_to_mime_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)

Comment: You lack in your example an association between user and file.  I.e. any logged in users can access any images.

Comment: The question is vague with no code examples. The OP asked how it's done and my explanation explains that. It's up to the OP to implement the code to determine whether the user is or isn't logged in. I've represented that with pseudo-code i.e. `logged_in()`. The code is merely an example with an explanation of how it's generally done. The question itself could be marked as subjective as there's many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

You can code a PHP file that will check if user is logged in, or if users have the permission to access the file.

*I'll assume your public directory is `public_html`.*

For the storage of images, you'll need to store them outside of the public directory (public_html).

Example Code (e.g. `image.php?file=profile_pic_mike_1`). `image.php` is in `public_html` and `profile_pic_mike_1` will be in the directory that is not accessible to the public.

```
<?php

// checking for $_SESSION, change accordingly to your method
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:index.php");
}

// $_GET['file'] will be profile_pic_mike_1
if(isset($_GET['file'])){

    $file_dir = "../";
    $file = $file_dir . $_GET["file"];

    // get if user has the permission
    // if yes, assign `true` to $permission ($permission = true;)

    if (!file_exists($file)) {

        echo "File not found.";

    } else if (!$permission) {

        echo "You do not have the permission to view this image.";

    } else {

        // You'll need to change the Content-type accordingly
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        readfile($file);
        exit;

    }

}

?>
```

List of `Content-type` for images: http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php.

You'll need to check if the user has the permission to view the file, one way to do it by saving the permissions in a MySQL DB.

Comment: You lack in your example an association between user and file. I.e. any logged in users can access any images.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to write the functions and flesh out a bit, but it gives you an idea:

```
<?php
$username = get_username_from_url();
$user     = get_logged_in_user();
if(!$user || ($username !== $user->name)) {
    // access denied, send appropriate header and exit.
}
// keep your images outside your web root (not public).
// e.g. /path/to/app/data/uploads/unique_id.jpg
$avatar_path = get_avatar_file_path_by_user($user);
// send image file
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); // or appropriate content type.
readfile($avatar_path);
```